# Why doesn't the Fedora Project provide Rawhide ISOs?

Tags: fedora

I need to do some work with some of the packages in Fedora 16 that are a major version larger than in Fedora 15, so I tried to bring up a VirtualBox VM using Fedora-15-x86_64-DVD.iso and using [only Rawhide yum repositories](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/Rawhide).  The install works, but the new system fails to boot; it hangs immediately upon startup.

My question is why doesn't Fedora provide ISOs of the latest packages?  It would sure be easier to work with the latest release of the operating system and take less time to install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Rawhide is out of date as soon as it is "mashed", much less once media has been generated. The only way to get a Rawhide system that isn't obsolete as soon as you install it is to perform a netinstall. And even that can become obsolete as you download the packages.

Comment: I don't mind updating the OS after it's freshly installed, having a day old RPMs is fine.  It's just getting the OS installed has been a pain and not working.

Comment: Rawhide isn't guaranteed to boot, so you're seeing nothing out of the ordinary.